# How to add picture to JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

How to add a picture to `JLabel`in Java?

Comment: there are other elements for picture why you want to use label for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html)

```
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("path-to-file"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("yourFilepth");
JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
```

For more [Info](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddIcontoJLabel.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Picture 34029.jpg"));
```

Here i posted the code that got generated automatically in netbeans.Hope my code helps in this regards keep coding goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply to the JLabel an `Icon` implementation (i.e `ImageIcon`). You can do it trough the `setIcon` method, as in your question, or through the `JLabel` constructor:

```
Image image=GenerateImage.toImage(true);  //this generates an image file
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); 
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(icon);
```

I recommend you to read the Javadoc for [`JLabel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), [`Icon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html), and [`ImageIcon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). Also, you can check the [How to Use Labels Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), for more information.

Also have a look at this tutorial: [Handling Images in a Java GUI Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html)